# How to bring the text to center of a header and give color to the text in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to bring the text to center of a header, and also have to give color to the text in Bootstrap. There is no Font-color or text-color option in  Bootstrap.

This is my HTML and CSS code

```css
#header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  color :white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="header" class="span12" style ="background-color :#003366; width :800px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; font-style :normal ;font-size:35px;">Customer</div>
```

And this is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: You can give `text-align: center;` to center **Customer**.

Comment: And for the text color, use the `color` property (e.g.: `color: #ff0000` for red)

Comment: i tried the both but both are not working

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate what you want?

Comment: i need to create one header . I am using  bootstrap. i want to bring that text Customer to the center of the header and also give different color to that text  and also if i shrink the size of the webpage it will also need to shrink depend upon the page size. how to do this in bootstrap

Comment: So, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: what do you mean they are not working? They are clearly working ([see demo in answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34460732/3695983)). You may have some conflict in the CSS that make them not work

Comment: If what you want is for the text to shrink with the page size, Bootstrap does it for you, so you wouldn't need to do anything. The issue is that you are defining a `font-size` inline, and that will override whatever values Bootstrap uses. Remove that property (and move the inline styling to the stylesheet if possible) and the text resizing should work fine too

Comment: yes my css also not working if i give anything in css and call it on html page no one is working which i gave in css

Comment: Then probably the CSS file is not being linked correctly. Check the console to see if you get any error, and verify the paths are correct.

Comment: before that i have one doubt . if we want to design a page using Bootstrap means what and all plugin code we need to use inside of our  application. Actually i followed this below method but still i feel like  bootstrap plugins are not working correctly inside of  my application.                                                     http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-4-step-by-step

Comment: Inspect the page source code and see if they are being loaded at all, and check the console for errors. The tutorial seems right (I've never done it that way though), you may have skipped a step or something

Comment: ok lets i have a check

Answer (score 1):

Use `color` (e.g.: `color:#bbddff;`) to change the color of the text, and `text-align:center` to specify the text to go in the center of the `div`. Like this:

```css
#header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  color :#bbddff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="header" class="span12" style ="background-color :#003366; width :800px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; font-style :normal ;font-size:35px;">Customer</div>
```

If this code doesn't work, you may have other styles conflicting with these ones. My recommendation:

1. Open your page on a browser.
2. Open the developer tools.
3. Inspect the `#header` element.
4. Review where it is getting the styles from.

Probably your styles are being overwritten somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="test-span">This is span.</span>

.test-span{
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 color:red;
}

Span is not a block element so to make text center in it, first need to make it block element and you can make that with above code.
```

To color any text use CSS property 'color' and give your value of choice (eg: color:blue;).

Comment: You can try with  class="text-center text-danger" , but if you want manually, then edit that div and set, font-color="color"

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center`
and 
`color: #FFFFFF`
for it to be white to the `#header` css

Answer (score 0):

You can use class="text-center" Here is an example.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
       <p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```